# Nested for lambda Java

Tags: java, lambda

could i use a nested for to do this example using lambda?

```
static int test(int[] n, int []m , int b) {

    int result = 0;
    List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();        

    for (int i : m) {
        for (int j : n) {
            result = i+j;
            if (result <=b) {
                list.add(result);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: so where do you want that lambda to be ?

Comment: Your method should return List and not int

Comment: Even your question is closed,  think about vote up/accept the answer if it satifies you ;)

Answer (score 4):

First, your method needs to return `List<Integer>` and not `int`

---

Then you can achieve with `Stream/lambda` as follows

- Iterate over first array `n`
- Get all the sum combinations with second array `m`
- Keep the ones which are inferior to `b`
- Boxe them from `int` to `Integer`
- Collect in a `List<>`

```
static List<Integer> test(int[] n, int[] m, int b) {
    return Arrays.stream(m)                                  // IntStream
            .flatMap(i -> Arrays.stream(n).map(j -> i + j))  // IntStream
            .filter(sum -> sum <= b)                         // IntStream 
            .boxed()                                         // Stream<Integer>
            .collect(Collectors.toList());                   // List<Integer>
}
```

Comment: Better to filter before boxing.